# Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Tags: php, regex

I got an error by this regular expression...

```
$strTmp = preg_replace('~(<\/CharacterStyleRange>(.*?)\n*</CharacterStyleRange>)~gim ' , "</CharacterStyleRange>", $strTmp);
```

Error

> **Warning**:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g' in ....

Why?

Answer (score 206):

`g` is implicit with `preg_replace()`. You don't need to include it.

Comment: See [the other good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061066/114558) on this question for more background.

Answer (score 56):

You don't have to specify the global flag. From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), there is a separate parameter (`$limit`) used to specify the number of replacements to make:

> **limit**
>   The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to *-1* (no limit).

So, unless you specify a positive number for this parameter, it will replace all occurrences by default:

```
$strTmp = preg_replace('~(<\/CharacterStyleRange>(.*?)\n*</CharacterStyleRange>)~im ' , "</CharacterStyleRange>", $strTmp);
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a `/` before the letter G in the string you're replacing.

Comment: this just threw that error for me  "Glasshouse Images/Getty Images"   My guess is preg_ sees that as an escape char