# preg_replace() with variable order of src, height and width

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I’m terrible with regex so I’m hoping someone can help! I’m trying to find any iframes that match any YouTube embeds in a document and replace them, for example any of the following:

```
<iframe src="http://youtube.com" width="100" height="200"></iframe>
<iframe src='http://youtube.com' width="100" height="200"></iframe>
<iframe width="100" src='http://youtube.com' width="100"></iframe>
etc.
```

Notice that there could be double quotes, single quotes, the order of the `src`, `height` and `width` attributes could vary etc. Can anyone help!

Comment: The last example uses `'` to open the `src` attribute and `"` to close it. Is that what you want?

Comment: @LinusKleen Seems like a copy-paste error, I’ve fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(<iframe.*?src=([\"\'])https?:\/\/w{0,3}.?youtube.com.*?(\2).*?\>)(.*?)(\<\/iframe\>)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/fF4vA6/6

Comment: Is there also a way to check for either http or https?

Comment: Here's my usage, I think its because I'm using preg_replace vs preg_match_all:
`$input = preg_replace('/(<iframe.*?src=[\"\']https:\/\/youtube.com[\"\'].*?\>)(.*?)(\<\/iframe\>)/gm', "test", $input, 1);`

Comment: mmm, maybe, the g to search all matches, and the m is for multi lines, maybe you don't need them ! 
I updated the regex to support http and https !

Comment: look this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061037/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier-g ,you don't need use the 'g' param ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I did see that, I'm using the following:
`$input = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tvrXet3Lx4U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$input = preg_replace('/(<iframe.*?src=[\"\']https?:\/\/youtube.com[\"\'].*?\>)(.*?)(\<\/iframe\>)/m', "test", $input, 1);`

But it seems like nothing is being changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91308/discussion-between-user2988034-and-mayo).