# Hide Price and Discount Text from WooCommerce Subscription Dropdown Options

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to remove the word "for", the pricing + discount sale and only display the subscription options like "Delivery every month" and "Delivery every 2 months," etc.

Instead of this

```
<select class="wcsatt-options-product-dropdown" name="convert_to_sub_dropdown2495">
 <option selected="true" value="1_month">Every month for $11.25 (10% off)
 </option><option value="2_month">Every 2 months for $11.25 (10% off)
 </option><option value="3_month">Every 3 months for $11.25 (10% off)
 </option><option value="4_month">Every 4 months for $11.25 (10% off)
 </option><option value="5_month">Every 5 months for $11.25 (10% off)
 </option><option value="6_month">Every 6 months for $11.25 (10% off)
 </option>
</select>
```

I need this

```
<select class="wcsatt-options-product-dropdown" name="convert_to_sub_dropdown2495">
<option selected="true" value="1_month">Every month</option>
<option value="2_month">Every 2 months</option>
<option value="3_month">Every 3 months</option>
<option value="4_month">Every 4 months</option>
<option value="5_month">Every 5 months</option>
<option value="6_month">Every 6 months</option>
</select>
```

[View product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7esjH.png)

I've managed to change the text, but I'm having trouble removing the pricing. Here's the hook I'm using.

```
function wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string( $price_string ) {
    // First, replace 'every' with 'Delivery every'
    $new_price = str_replace('every', 'Delivery every', $price_string);
    
    // Now, use a regular expression to remove ' months for $X.XX'
    // This assumes that the price is always in the format of $ followed by any number of digits, a dot, and exactly two digits
    $new_price = preg_replace('/ months for \$\d+\.\d+/', '', $new_price);
    
    // Optionally, if you also want to remove the '(10% off)' part, you can add another line like this:
    // $new_price = preg_replace('/ \(.*?% off\)/', '', $new_price);
    
    return $new_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
```

Comment: you're having trouble replacing the price or the discount? I ask because the commented `preg_replace` in your code regards the discount

Comment: also, no need for `javascript` and `jquery` tags here

Comment: Sure, I took off those tags. Every subscription has a 10% discount. The client wants us to only display how often the delivery happens, without showing the price.

Comment: like this? https://regex101.com/r/MjYykb/1 (this might not work without newlines)

Comment: this one should work without newlines https://regex101.com/r/oJ9ypr/1

Comment: So like this? 

function wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string( $price_string ) {
    // Replace 'every' with 'Delivery every'
    $new_price = str_replace('every', 'Delivery every', $price_string);

    // Use regex to remove the price and discount part
    $new_price = preg_replace('/\$.*<\/option>/', '', $new_price);

    return $new_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscription_price_string', 'wc_subscriptions_custom_price_string' );

Comment: GrafiCode, the examples you sent is what I'm aiming for. Tried modifying that hook with the regex but no luck. The prices is still showing in the dropdowns.

Comment: it should be just `$new_price = preg_replace('/(Every )(month|\d months)(.*?(<\/option>))/gm', "$1$2$4", $price_string);` commenting the rest.

Comment: I'm getting a warning message indicates that the 'g' modifier is not recognized by the preg_replace() function in PHP. Thanks but still no luck. I've been trying all day to remove the price. Pain. lol

Comment: warning is normal, I'm reading the g flag is implicit in preg_replace (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061037/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier-g), but the replacement should work, not sure what's happening